# How to create service that will execute periodically bash script (with ssh connection)

Tags: bash, scripts, ssh, services

I am having bash script that checks for ssh connection in `lsof`. In case it's down, it will open it once again.

I found some information how to create service that starts periodically, but the problem is, that whenever it will start service, and run `ssh` connection, after exit of service this connection dies.

I know that there is an option `RemainAfterExit=yes`, but it will remain service `active` after execution.

**So in nutshell:**

1. I want to start bash script periodically
2. script checks for ssh
3. If tunnel is down, it will start it **(and leave it in system)**
4. Service needs to start once again run script for ssh check

**My service configuration:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Periodically check for ssh tunnel
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/script.sh -s

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

**EDIT:**

In my script with -s parameter I am just calling function which is checking if ssh tunnel is established for particular address, and if no, it'll just open it using standard ssh.

```
if [[ $(sudo lsof -i -n | egrep '\<ssh\>' | grep "$ip" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then
            INFO "Tunnel is established for IP "$ip"."
            exit 0
else
            ERROR "Tunnel for IP "$ip" has been disconnected. Trying to reconnect."
            ssh -fN user@10.0.9.63
fi
```

Comment: You could also look at `autossh` to keep ssh open.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details about step 3: what does "tunnel down" mean, and how do you start it in your script? Ideally, add the script to your question or at least the relevant parts. I'm not familiar with sshuttle, but if "tunnel down" means the sshuttle process exited and "start it" means start sshuttle, creating a restarting service unit for sshuttle itself would make more sense.

Comment: @danzel, thanks for message. This sshuttle was not relevant, it was put there by mistake. It is just standard ssh. I am checking for "tunnel down" directly from lsof